# Determining value of PAGE_OFFSET?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

How can I determine the value of PAGE_OFFSET for the Kernel I am building ?
I am building the Kernel for an ARM platform.

Thanks,
vj

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the value of PAGE_OFFSET as a value defined under .config, against CONFIG_PAGE_OFFSET=0xC0000000.

Answer (score 1):

Take X86_32 arch for example.

arch/x86/include/asm/page_types.h :

```
#define PAGE_OFFSET     ((unsigned long)__PAGE_OFFSET)
```

arch/x86/include/asm/page_32_types.h :

```
#define __PAGE_OFFSET       _AC(CONFIG_PAGE_OFFSET, UL)
```

arch/x86/Kconfig:

```
config PAGE_OFFSET
    hex
    default 0xB0000000 if VMSPLIT_3G_OPT
    default 0x80000000 if VMSPLIT_2G
    default 0x78000000 if VMSPLIT_2G_OPT
    default 0x40000000 if VMSPLIT_1G
    default 0xC0000000
    depends on X86_32
```

The PAGE_OFFSET in arch/x86/Kconfig is the CONFIG_PAGE_OFFSET in page_32_types.h. Because the prefix 'CONFIG_'  is added by *make system* automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the kernel source code

```
grep -rn "#define PAGE_OFFSET" arch/arm/*
```

It finds that is defined in `arch/arm/include/asm/memory.h` but it depends on your kernel configuration. Follow the symbol according to your condiguration and you will get the value.

Or you can use a [Linux kernel web explorer](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=PAGE_OFFSET)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the value using the C pre-processor during compilation:

```
+#define STRING2(x) #x
+#define STRING(x) STRING2(x)
+#pragma message "PAGE_OFFSET = " STRING(PAGE_OFFSET)
```

This will print the value in the console running make.